# Оптимальное хранение данных в бд

Tags: оптимизация, sql

Что лучше для быстродействия, 2 таблицы по 15 столбцов в каждой, или 6 таблиц по 5 столбцов в каждой? БД - SQL

Comment: Иными словами вы хотите узнать когда стоит применять денормализацию бд, а когда нет. По своему опыту скажу, что денормализацию иногда приходится применять при большом количестве данных во избежание лишних джоинов. Если же бд маленькая то смысла нет. А вообще все зависит от контекста решаемой задачи.

Comment: > А вообще все зависит от контекста решаемой задачи.

соглашусь с только с этим

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотря какая цель задачи или какой запрос будете выполнять. Часто в моих проектах приходилось разбивать таблицы под каждый вид данных (Ваш 2 вариант). Вообщем, не заморачивайтесь вы так, делайте как удобно, если все-же интересует вопрос, дополните данные.

Comment: Я подразумевал, что маленькие таблицы отвечают за свой вид данных

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял, то 2 вариант будет быстрее, но надо ли Вам это? Ведь там на такие считанные миллисекунд, что думаю, тут надо думать на удобность разработки чем на оптимизацию в данном случае.

Answer (score 2):

Общее правило: чем меньше таблиц - тем быстрее это очевидно. Но, если количество таблиц диктуется нормализацией данных, то ненормализованные данные, в плане поддержки и сохранения целостности данных могут создать серьезные проблемы.

Есть конечно частные случаи, когда множественные таблицы дают выигрыш в скорости. Простой пример: в 1-м текстовом поле хранятся различные классификаторы (типа 1-й символ отвечает за тип данных, 2-й символ за стиль, 3-й за еще что-то), если это нормализовать и сделать нормальные ссылки на отдельные таблицы классификаторов с привязкой к ключевому полю, то второй вариант будет работать быстрее.